# Como puedo solucionar este error en TypeScript al momento de realizar la transpilacion

Tags: typescript

Al momento de hacer la transpilacion del .ts al JavaScript .js no me genera como tal el .js si no que me genera un archivo completamente vacio y como nombre tsc.¿Que debería hacer para solucionar esto? por favor ayúdenme.

Codigo:

```
   function saludar( nombre:String ){

   console.log("Hola" +nombre);

}


var wolverine = {
  nombre: "Felipe"
};
saludar(wolverine.nombre);
```

el codigo como tal esta bien pero no se que pasa al realizar la transpilacion que no me genera como tal el .js algo estara mal con mi pc que puedo hacer?

[image: Inreso el tsc para generar el javascript]

[image: al momento de darle enter me genera esto]

[image: Y como tal me genera un archivo tsc completamente vacio pero me deberia generar un app.js]

Comment: ¿Por qué abres `tsc` al final?¿Dónde está el resultado de `tsc app.ts`? Deberías añadir el código como texto para que podamos comprobar si funciona correctamente.

Comment: Chema ese es el resultado al generar el tsc app.ts osea me genera ese documento tsc sin nada adentro no se si sera por algo mal instalado o que seria? por que hasta con otro editor me sale lo mismo un documento llamado tsc y vacio no me genera como tan la tranpilacion .js

Comment: Es imposible saber qué pasa sólo con esas imágenes. Muestra la salida de los siguientes comandos: `dir`, `npm ls -g --depth=0`, `npx tsc app.ts` y `where tsc`.

Answer (score 0):

Oye ChemaCortes soy yo Felipe el de la pregunta

gracias bro si funiona si le añado npx antes del tsc si me funcionan los comandos tsc muchas gracias hermano pero por que toca con el npx?

Bro aca te voy a te voy a decir que pasa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca le añadi el npx para que reconociera el codigo where tsc y me salio esto. esto en el visual code.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aca si me ejecuta en el cdm si me ejecuta bien el where sin el npx te adjunto las imagenes para ver que opinas

Comment: Poco puedo decir si no añades más información. `npx` ejecuta un binario node sin tener que instarlarlo. Seguramente tengas una instalación de typescript defectuosa o que tengas algún ejecutable con nombre `tsc` que no haga nada. Prueba con `where tsc` a ver dónde está ese ejecutable.

Comment: Si lo perdí el acceso. Voy a tratar de explicarte bien la situacion. En mi ide sea atom o visual code si quiero ejecutar el codigo tsc en la parte de comandos este solo me genera un archivo de nombre tsc completamente vacio peero si me dirijo al cdm=simbolo del sistema y me dirijo hasta donde esta el directorio de mi proyecto y ejecuto el tsc ejemplo = tsc app.ts por esa parte si me funcionan los tsc y me genera el app.js y no se si sera por lo que dices que esta mal instalado el TypeScript o sera ya por mis ides que les falta algo o que? que opinas tu Chema?

Comment: @ChemaCortes en edite el comentario de respuesta para que veas que sucede

Comment: @ChemaCortes aca esta un link donde formule otra pregunta que es de esto mismo solo que ya con este usuario que tengo  [Nuevo lugar de pregunta con este usuario nuevo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/444542/como-puedo-este-solucionar-error-en-el-lector-de-codigo-atom-y-visual-code)

Comment: ya pedi que te unieran los usuarios. Pero para que sepas, las imagenes son malas y no se ven!!! mejor agrega el codigo y los errores como texto...