# como puedo este solucionar error en el lector de codigo Atom y Visual code

Tags: javascript, typescript

Al momento de hacer la transpilacion del .ts al JavaScript .js no me genera como tal el .js si no que me genera un archivo completamente vacio y como nombre tsc.¿Que debería hacer para solucionar esto? por favor ayúdenme. Esto pasa en los lectores de codigo Atom o Visual code pero si realizo la transpilacion desde el cdm si me genera normalmente el .js que sera?

Codigo:

```
function saludar( nombre:String ){

   console.log("Hola" +nombre);

}


var wolverine = {
  nombre: "Felipe"
};
saludar(wolverine.nombre);
```

el codigo como tal esta bien pero no se que pasa al realizar la transpilacion que no me genera como tal el .js algo estara mal con mi pc que puedo hacer?
[image: ingresoel codigo tsc app.ts]

[image: me genera esto]
[image: Y me genera un documento llamado tsc vacio cuando me deberia estar arrojando un app.js]

Aca con el whuere tsc

```
C:\Users\Felipe Cruz>where tsc

C:\Windows\System32\tsc
C:\Users\Felipe Cruz\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc
C:\Users\Felipe Cruz\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd
```

Aca con el path

```
C:\Users\Felipe Cruz>path
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Felipe Cruz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Felipe Cruz\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Felipe Cruz\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Felipe Cruz\AppData\Local\atom\bin
```

y al moemnto de ir al directorio que me dices me sale es con que aplicacion deseo abrir ese documento pero entre hasta donde dices y me sale = tsc con un peso de 0 KB

Comment: Añade las salidas de los comandos `where tsc` y `path`. Parece que no tienes bien configurada la variable de entorno `PATH`. ¿Puedes abrir y ver qué hay en `C:\windows\System32\tsc` y qué información te da el explorador de ficheros sobre él?

Comment: @ChemaCorte en arriba esta lo que me dices

Comment: Como nota, esto no es una red social. Etiquetar a la gente en una publicacion no hace absolutamente nada, y en los comentarios solo funciona si dicha persona participo antes de la conversacion. Dicho esto, esta pedido que te fusionen los usuarios por la perdida que tuviste.

Comment: @gbianchi asi si estoy realizando bien esto?

Comment: perfecto. cualquier otro etiquetado no sirve para absolutamente nada... no llegan notificaciones.

Comment: Dices que el `tsc` de `C:\windows\System32\tsc` está vacío. No tiene que estar ahí y, posiblemente, es el que intenta abrir atom y vscode. Bórralo y debería ir todo bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias @ChemaCortes. De momento ahora si me deja usar los codigos tsc desde atom y visual por que ocurrio que se genero ese archivo tsc vacio?

Comment: No tengo ni idea. Puede que atom lo haya intentado crear como acceso directo a su propio typescript, pero sólo es una conjetura.